# String: substringToIndex for unicode scalars

Tags: ios, swift

To get the first 50 characters of a `String`, I can do

```
s.substringToIndex(s.startIndex.advancedBy(50)))
```

How can I get the first 50 unicode scalars of a `String`?

I can get a `String.UnicodeScalarView` object using `s.unicodeScalars` but I don't know how to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s.unicodeScalars` returns a `String.UnicodeScalarView` which conforms
to `CollectionType`. You can get a subsequence of the collection with

```
u = s.unicodeScalars
u[u.startIndex ..< u.startIndex.advancedBy(50)]
```

or, in the case of an initial sequence, more simply with

```
u.prefix(50)
```

There is a small difference: Subscripting *requires* that the specified
subrange exists, and will terminate with a runtime exception otherwise.
`prefix()` *truncates* at the given index, i.e. it returns a subsequence
with 50 or less elements.